# What's the difference between /sbin/nologin and /bin/false

Tags: shell, security, login

Technically, unless `pam` is set up to check your shell with `pam_shells` neither of these can actually prevent your login, if you're not on the shell. On my system they are even different sizes, so I suspect they actually do something. So what's the difference? why do they both exist? Why would I use one over the other?

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  21K Feb  4 17:01 /bin/false
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4.7K Mar  2 14:59 /sbin/nologin
```

Comment: See also [Does /usr/sbin/nologin as a login shell serve a security purpose?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155139/does-usr-sbin-nologin-as-a-login-shell-serve-a-security-purpose)

Comment: The path `/bin/false` should exist everywhere but not `/sbin/nologin`: '/sbin/nologin': No such file or directory.
Any idea why it is `/usr/sbin/nologin` instead of `/sbin/nologin` on Debian and Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm curious why /bin/false takes 21k of code to return a "1" return code!  (and /sbin/nologin only takes 4.7k)

Comment: useful to read. [What is the difference between /sbin/nologin and /bin/false](https://serverfault.com/questions/519215/what-is-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false)

Comment: @MarkStewart A bit too late, but you may want to read [Why are true and false so large?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/419697/243481) and [A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](https://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).

Comment: @nxnev Yeah didn't think about the overhead of ELF.  And from my old IBM days there was a program IEFBR14 that was a simple one op-code assembly instruction: BR 14 -- Branch to register 14, which would terminate the program with the return code set to whatever was in register 14!

Answer (score 286, accepted):

When `/sbin/nologin` is set as the shell, if user with that shell logs in, they'll get a polite message saying 'This account is currently not available.' This message can be changed with the file `/etc/nologin.txt`.

`/bin/false` is just a binary that immediately exits, returning false, when it's called, so when someone who has `false` as shell logs in, they're immediately logged out when `false` exits. Setting the shell to `/bin/true` has the same effect of not allowing someone to log in but `false` is probably used as a convention over `true` since it's much better at conveying the concept that person doesn't have a shell.

Looking at `nologin`'s man page, it says it was created in 4.4 BSD (early 1990s) so it came long after `false` was created. The use of `false` as a shell is probably just a convention carried over from the early days of UNIX.

`nologin` is the more user-friendly option, with a customizable message given to the user trying to log in, so you would theoretically want to use that; but both `nologin` and `false` will have the same end result of someone not having a shell and not being able to ssh in.

Comment: `/usr/sbin/nologin` for Debian based distributions.

Comment: At least BSD implementation also logs the login attempts to syslog as seen in https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-735/nologin.tproj/nologin.c , whereas /bin/false wouldn't log anything

Comment: THIS - Is an amazing answer, with great history presented here. Well done Mark!

Comment: The `/etc/nologin.txt` custom message feature is not available in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 38):

Some FTP servers will allow you FTP access only if you have a valid shell.  `/sbin/nologin` is regarded as a valid shell, whereas `/bin/false` is not.

(I think "valid" means its exit status is 0, but `/etc/shells` may also come into it, it probably depends on the system, the FTP software, and your configuration.)

Comment: yeah, that's probably part of the ftp program using pam, and pam using pam_shells which as you said, checks `/etc/shells`. Just a guess... I could be wrong.

Comment: I just checked both Ubuntu 8.04 and 14.04. The nologin command exits with status 1 similar to false, and none of true, false, or nologin are included in /etc/shells. If they were, a user could use chsh to select such a shell and lock himself out of his account.

Answer (score 19):

`/bin/false` is a system command that is used anytime you need to pass a command to a program that should do nothing more than exit with an error.  It's the companion to `/bin/true`.  Both of these are very old and standard POSIX utilities and neither produce any output by definition.  true is sometimes used for a shell script that should loop indefinitely, like:

```
while true; do
    ...
    # Waste time
    if [ $wasted_time -gt 100000 ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    ...
done
```

`/usr/sbin/nologin` is specifically designed to replace a shell and produces output complaining you can't log-in.  Before it existed, it was common to use `/bin/false` for dummy users, but could be confusing since the user doesn't know why they're kicked off.

Comment: worth noting that `/bin/true` and `/bin/false` are not always what you will get in a shell script. In `zsh` `true` and `false` are built-ins, where `bash` uses the `/bin/*` versions

Answer (score 5):

On my machine, `nologin` displays always the same message, in English, ignoring arguments. `/bin/false` responds to `--version` and `--help` in the language indicated by `$LC_CTYPE`. Other than these cosmetic differences, they have the same effect.

Usability-wise, `nologin` is better if it's used on the account of a real person who speaks English. Security-wise, there is no difference.

Comment: seems like perhaps `false` is more for system accounts that have no real user, and `nologin` is for disabled accounts.

Comment: What is your OS? Centos `nologin` version takes no arguments, but can read message from `/etc/nologin.txt` .

Answer (score 3):

/bin/false only job is to exit with a non-zero exit code.

Try it at the command line:

```
$:> /bin/false
$:> echo $?
1
$:>
```

Some institutions use /bin/false in the shell field of the password file. If  user tries to login, the shell is /bin/false, so they are exited right away

Answer (score 3):

On linux, `/sbin/nologin` comes from the [util-linux](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Util-linux) project, while `/bin/false` is part of [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils).  They serve different roles, and nologin has the option of printing a message for people who have it as their shell who are logging in.  The linux commands come from BSD, where they seem to have a long history of being different.  [The FreeBSD `false` simply returns 1](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.bin/false/false.c?rev=1.6), while the `nologin` checks to make sure it's [running on a TTY and sends a message to syslog during login attempts.](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/src/usr.sbin/nologin/nologin.c?rev=1.6)  The linux versions are a bit more complicated (`false` doing all sorts of fun stuff with internationalization for the output of --help, I assume) but essentially perform the same way.

Answer (score 1):

They could be the same program, but they have different meanings.  The program name tells it all.

- /bin/false is intended to return a false value.  It is run as program.
- /bin/nologin is intended to indicate to the user that no login is permitted for an account.  (It is used a login shell.)

Answer (score -6):

Both does more or less the same job but `/bin/false` is useful for non-privileged users . On the other hand, `/sbin/nologin` is for privileged users.

Comment: Oh, how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: Probably he has looked into `/etc/passwd`. I just had a look into `/etc/passwd` of a freshly installed Debian stretch. On this box, nearly all system accounts (user ids < 1000) have `/usr/sbin/nologin` as shell, with a few exceptions. Please note that I do not agree with @pythondetective's answer. I am just speculating what might have lead him to this conclusion. My comment is a little bit late, though.

Comment: no!  default login shell is not the same as privileges.