# what is the difference between "/sbin/nologin" and "/bin/false"?

Tags: binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between /sbin/nologin and /bin/false](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false)

They are not having the same size. In what do they differ?

Comment: Why 'possible' duplicate? Maybe we should flag it for closing?