# Correct way to create users without home (for shadow.service)

Tags: arch-linux, passwd

If you create a user without a home on Arch Linux with `useradd -M test`, an entry like the following is created in `/etc/passwd`:

```
test:x:1001:1001::/home/test:/bin/bash
```

But because `/home/test` doesn't exist, this causes `shadow.service` to fail.
Leaving the home directory blank will produce the same error.
I found [an old thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=183975) suggesting to use `/dev/null`, but I'm not sure if that's the best solution. ATM, ignoring it seems like the best solution, but maybe there is a better way.

---

`shadow.service` boils down to `pwck` and `grpck`:

```
### [...]
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/pwck -r || r=1; /usr/bin/grpck -r && exit $r
### [...]
```

Comment: you'll find other accounts in `/etc/passwd` which do not require or should have a home directory (which is nothing new) and I believe the proper method or convention to do such a thing is with either `/bin/true` or `/bin/false` specified as the home directory.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10852/whats-the-difference-between-sbin-nologin-and-bin-false

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/29359/how-to-add-a-user-without-home

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what you are referencing is about the shell and not the home. `(usermod) -s` specifies the shell. `/bin/false` would be a regular file, that could cause issues (try `cd /bin/false`). However upon closer inspection, many stock `nologin` users have just `/` as their home...

Comment: yeah you are correct,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Debian-based

If you are on a Debian-based system, the new - already somewhat present by default in multiple debian-based distributions, (as well as already included in the source code of both `pwck` and `login.defs` of the next `shadow-utils` package release) proper way to account for nonexistent home directories is with the `/nonexistent` path.

If you actually get the newest `shadow-utils` package , it will allow you to configure your `/etc/login.defs` and add (or uncomment) the following option:

This is from the new `man 8 pwck` from the latest commit:

> ```
>    NONEXISTENT (string)
>       If a system account intentionally does not have a home directory
>       that exists, this string can be provided in the /etc/passwd entry
>       for the account to indicate this. The result is that pwck will
>       not emit a spurious warning for this account.
> ```

and the actual option belongs in `/etc/login.defs` like so

```
# The [string] can be whatever word/path you want to use in your /etc/passwd file to
# correspond to a nonexistent directory. However, /nonexistent should be used as the default 
# nonexisting home directory, as that is already in use in many distributions. 

NONEXISTENT [string]
```

This option has been added specifically for `pwck` to account for nonexistent home directories, which is the underlying command used by the `shadow.service` that checks the validity and integrity of `/etc/passwd` using the configuration provided in `/etc/login.defs`.

If you do use this configuration option, then using `sudo adduser -M -d /nonexistent [username]` followed by `pwck -r` will not throw an error.

---

#### Other distributions

While many Debian-based distributions already use this approach for this particular situation, there are other variants which use their own system to account for nonexistent home directories.

However, you can usually test how your distribution already determines the nonexistent home directory situation, by executing

```
sudo grep nobody /etc/passwd
```

as this particular non-privileged user will never by default have its own home directory path, yet the corresponding value found in your `/etc/passwd` will give you a clue of how your system already deals with it.

For example:

- RHEL/CentOS uses `/` as a fail-safe for home directory of `nobody` yet disables its login shell through `/sbin/nologin`
- Debian-based distros currently use `/nonexistent` for home directory, and `/usr/sbin/nologin` for the shell
- SUSE Linux, until at least mid 2019, used  `/var/lib/nobody` for the directory and `/bin/bash` for the shell, but some security-conscious memos suggest a change to `/var/lib/nobody` and `/bin/false`
- OSx used and might still use  `/var/empty` and `/usr/bin/false` for `nobody`
- I have encountered other distributions that use `/nonexistent` yet allow for shell with `/bin/sh`

---

The issue with using `sudo useradd [username]` is that it specifically allows for system preset options in `/etc/login.defs` to be overwritten at execution, even if they may violate the integrity of `/etc/passwd`.

I have not tested `useradd` in a while, but - unless significant changes have been made to the source code - the validator for the `-d` option flag had many limitations. There was certainly a check present for whether `optarg[0]` of the provided path is indeed `/` and whether a path contains `:` but every test I ran using `*`   , and hence I would not be surprised if `sudo useradd -d /home/my:base [username]` actually executed without error.

Comment: It looks like arch hasn't adopted `NONEXISTENT` yet. So I guess it would have to be a real directory until then. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I might add to this that while RHEL/CentOS does not seem to have `NONEXISTENT  /nonexistent` set in `/etc/login.defs`, you can still use `/nonexisting` as a home directory for system users (i.e. with UID in the range 201-999), e.g. when running `useradd` with the `--system` flag. This is because `pwck` does not check if directories exist for UID's in the system range. In fact, in my CentOS install the user for the cockpit service has home directory set as `/nonexisting` by default.