# What is the point of creating a user without a home directory?

Tags: linux, users, home

While reading useradd manual pages, see that `useradd  -M user` creates a user without home directory and I can not figure out what is the purpose on it.

I am new on sysadmin topics and do not know much about it.

Answer (score 12):

You may possibly want to use `-M` with `useradd` if the new user's home directory already exists.

Note that the `-M` option turns off *the creation* of the user's home directory.  You may use `-d` to assign a home directory to the new user while at the same time using `-M`.

It would be highly unusual to create a user with no home directory defined at all. Most daemon accounts (accounts associated with services) and other system accounts have home directories, although some may well have *non-existing* home directories, such as the `_apt` user on Ubuntu:

```
$ getent passwd _apt
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

Also related: [Correct way to create users without home (for shadow.service)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617531/correct-way-to-create-users-without-home-for-shadow-service)

Comment: If you have a network of machines, the user's home directory might not even be on the same machine. In that situation, *you* might not have the admin permissions to create it even if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I have a NAS (ZFS) with users data. on the NAS, user don't have to have a home drive as they will never access that, but will require a user account to connect to their SMB share/s. In this case you will create the user account without the home directory.
also system user (service account in Windows world) will not require a home directory either.